# Cannot output to text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script is not writing to the text file I have specified and I can't figure out why. The script currently logs into the remote server and as far as I can tell it's executing the powershell job correctly of gather the data. I initially was attempting to log out of the remote session then write the data, but the variable `$Data` did not retain the data.

```
Add-PSSnapin vmware.vimautomation.core #required for vm-cmdlets
$User = [Environment]::UserName
$Workstation = [Environment]::MachineName

$Log = "\\folder\user$\name\CompasFound.txt"
$Search_Dir = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\$User\Documents\WheresMyCompass.txt

$Servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\$User\Documents\WheresMyWorkStation.txt

#Enter-PSSession -Computer vmname
Connect-VIServer -Server 192.168.x.x -User "user" -Pass "pass"

Function CompassFinder #Finding Compass file(s) function
{
    Start-Job -Name CompFind -ScriptBlock{
        $Data = Get-Childitem -Path $Search_Dir -Recurse  *.doc; 
        #Exit-PSSession; #Breaking remote session
        $Data | Format-Table -AutoSize | Add-Content $Log  #Writing data
        }
}

Function GenLogFinder  #Finding GeneralLog file function
{
    Start-Job -Name LogFind -ScriptBlock{
        $GLogData = Get-Childitem -Path $Search_Dir -Recurse -Include GeneralLog.txt;
        #Exit-PSSession; #Breaking remote session
        $GLogData = Format-Table -AutoSize | Add-Content $Log -append; #Writing data
    }
}

CompassFinder;
GenLogFinder;
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that Add-Content does not have an -append parameter and yet you are trying to provide one. It doesn't make much sense to give an append parameter to a cmdlet whose sole purpose is to add to existing content AKA appending.

Comment: I apologize about that. I initially had `out-file`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't do typo here?

```
$GLogData = Format-Table
```

Should it be `|` instead of `=`?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell variables must be explicitly passed into script blocks:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  param( $Search_Dir, $Log )
  $Data = Get-Childitem -Path $Search_Dir -Recurse  *.doc
  $Data | Format-Table -AutoSize | Add-Content $Log
} -ArgumentList $Search_Dir, $Log
```

Otherwise the script block will use new (empty) variables `$Search_Dir` and `$Log`.

For simple script blocks just using the `$args` array would be another option:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  $Data = Get-Childitem -Path $args[0] -Recurse  *.doc
  $Data | Format-Table -AutoSize | Add-Content $args[1]
} -ArgumentList $Search_Dir, $Log
```

Answer (score 0):

The current structure of my program was writing odd data to the text file because of the `Format-Table` line.